Intuition for the fact that the gradient shows in the direction of the steepest ascent
Whats the intuition behind the fact that the gradient of a differentiable function $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ shows in the direction of the steepest ascent?
I know how to proof it rigorously but I still have problems to see a clear intuition behind it.
If we for example consider the function $f(x,y)= 2x + y$, then $grad(f)_{(x,y)}=(2,1)^T$. Shouldn’t this function grow more in x-direction than in y-direction? So why isn‘t $(1,0)^T$ the (normed) direction of the steepest ascent?

It does grow more in the $x$-direction than the $y$-direction, but what about all the directions in between? We don't need to restrict ourselves to just cardinal directions

@whpowell96 Good point, but from my naive point of view every linear combination of x- and y- direction should be less steep than just going all in x-direction.

While maximizing $2a+b$ subject to $a+b=1$ with $a,,b\ge0$ takes $a=1,,b=0$, maximizing $2a+b$ subject to $a^2+b^2=1$, which is what matters here, takes $a=2b$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. You can get a geometric intuition for it, if you think about where circles' radii meet their tangents.

if  you have fixed $f(a_0,b_0) = c_0, $  what is the $t$ derivative of $f(a_0 + t \cos \theta, ; b_0 + t \sin \theta)  ; ; ? ; ; ; $  For what $\theta$  is that derivative largest?

Imagine a perfectly level road on a hillside.  If you are climbing the hill, the direction of greatest ascent should be perpendicular to the road. The road will be on a path where $z$ does not change, so in the case of a hill $z = 2x + y$, the road through $(0,0)$ would run along a path $x = t, y = -2t$.  So the direction of steepest ascent should be perpendicular to $(1, -2)$.
